# Por que deve-se usar o extern em uma variável declarada em um arquivo de cabeçalho?

Tags: c++

Eu estava pesquisando a fundo sobre arquivos de cabeçalho em C++ depois que eu frequentemente recebi o erro `LNK2005` na compilação do Visual Studio, e percebi que o erro era que eu estava declarando uma variável duas vezes, no arquivo de cabeçalho e no main.cpp, e também encontrei vários usuários dando a solução como usar o `extern tipo nome_da_variavel;` no arquivo de cabeçalho como solução pra isso, e lendo as respostas, me veio 3 dúvidas na cabeça:

**1ª** - Precisa realmente usar o `extern` para declarar variáveis de qualquer tipo em um arquivo de cabeçalho? Se sim, por que então ele não é usado em declaração de uma classe em arquivo de cabeçalho, por exemplo?

**2ª** - É uma boa prática usar o `extern` no arquivo de cabeçalho? Ou existe algo melhor para se usar e que não dê o erro que eu recebi acima?

**3ª** - Pelo que eu li, o uso do `extern` requer que eu re-declare a variável também no arquivo.cpp, mas se ela já está declarada no arquivo de cabeçalho, por que não posso simplesmente setar o valor dela no .cpp?

**PS:** Aqui vai os motivos de eu ter pesquisado a fundo sobre arquivos de cabeçalho e ter gerado esta pergunta aqui:

toast_notification.h:

```
#pragma once

bool dollar_value_was_changed;
bool toast_notification_was_created;

void show_toast_notification(), create_and_initialize_toast_notification(), set_toast_notification();
bool is_windows_10();
```

toast_notification.cpp:

```
#include "toast_notification.h"

#include <Windows.h>
#include <VersionHelpers.h>
#include <wintoast/wintoastlib.h>

void show_toast_notification()
{
    if (is_windows_10())
    {
        if (!toast_notification_was_created)
            create_and_initialize_toast_notification();
    }
}

bool is_windows_10()
{
    if (IsWindows10OrGreater())
        return true;
    else
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Teste", L"Título da janela?", MB_OK);

        return false;
    }
}

void create_and_initialize_toast_notification()
{
    WinToastLib::WinToast::instance()->setAppName(L"Toast Dollar");
    WinToastLib::WinToast::instance()->setAppUserModelId(WinToastLib::WinToast::configureAUMI(L"Teste", L"Toast Dollar"));
    WinToastLib::WinToast::instance()->initialize();

    toast_notification_was_created = true;
}

void set_toast_notification()
{
    WinToastLib::WinToastTemplate toast_notification = WinToastLib::WinToastTemplate(WinToastLib::WinToastTemplate::Text02);
    toast_notification.setTextField(L"Teste", WinToastLib::WinToastTemplate::FirstLine);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "toast_notification.h"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    
    show_toast_notification();

    system("pause");
}
```

Não liguem muito para o código, eu peço que voltem a atenção para a variável `toast_notification_was_created`, que na minha cabeça, como ela já estava declarada no arquivo de cabeçalho, eu poderia setá-la no .cpp, além dela, a variável `dollar_value_was_changed` (que não foi usada) também gerou o erro que me fez formular essa pergunta

Os erros:

```
1>toast_notification.obj : error LNK2005: "bool dollar_value_was_changed" (?dollar_value_was_changed@@3_NA) já definida no main.obj
```

```
1>toast_notification.obj : error LNK2005: "bool toast_notification_was_created" (?toast_notification_was_created@@3_NA) já definida no main.obj
```

Comment: Amigo, na 2 eu acredito que não haja problemas, e na 3, vale salientar que cabeçalho é como se fosse um dicionário para o .cpp, não faz sentido eu adicionar valor lá.

Answer (score 0):

sim, você precisa do "extern", assim como quando você declara uma função sem código:

```
bool is_windows_10();
```

usar extern em uma variável não ira definir ela, só irá dizer q ela existe em algum lugar...

isto porque os arquivos cpp poderão ser compilados juntos ou separadamente em objetos...

e provavelmente a menos que você use diretamente o compilador, ele ira compilar separadamente.

e na hora de linkar eles, se não houver um "extern", cada objeto terá sua definição para aquela váriavel, pós o compilador seguira processando todos os "include" para cada cpp recursivamente para gerar o objeto(.o), oque vai causar conflito na hora de reunir estes objetos em um executavel/lib/so/dll, então, você deve colocar "extern" nas váriaveis do header, e em apenas um dos cpp "atribuir" uma definição para aquela variável usando "static" com o valor inicial, oque fará apenas o objeto daquele cpp ter a definição, e ao linker reuni-los não haver nem um duplicata!

porque diferentes objetos? simples: compilando cada arquivo para um objeto, o compilador pode cuidar de grandes projetos com muitos arquivos, tirando proveito dos múltiplos núcleos de um processador moderno.

Comment: Isso aqui está estragando a resposta: _"porque diferentes objetos? simples: compilando cada arquivo para um objeto, o compilador pode cuidar de grandes projetos com muitos arquivos, tirando proveito dos múltiplos núcleos de um processador moderno."_ - não tem relação nenhuma a organização em objetos com núcleos múltiplos (tanto que era assim já antes de se falar em núcleos múltiplos). O fato de eventualmente poder fazer compilação em paralelo é mero efeito colateral. Objetos tem a ver com organização, de certa forma escopo, e com o que será usado de fato ao "linkar" o output final.